# Sum pandas dataframe column values based on condition of column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with column names in the shape of `x.y`, where I would like to sum up all columns with the same value on `x` without having to explicitly name them. That is, the value of `column_name.split(".")[0]` should determine their group. Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x.1': [1,2,3,4], 'x.2': [5,4,3,2], 'y.8': [19,2,1,3], 'y.92': [10,9,2,4]})

df
Out[3]: 
   x.1  x.2  y.8  y.92
0    1    5   19    10
1    2    4    2     9
2    3    3    1     2
3    4    2    3     4
```

The result should be the same as this operation, only I shouldn't have to explicitly list the column names and how they should group.

```
pd.DataFrame({'x': df[['x.1', 'x.2']].sum(axis=1), 'y': df[['y.8', 'y.92']].sum(axis=1)})

   x   y
0  6  29
1  6  11
2  6   3
3  6   7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first create `Multiindex` by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then `groupby` by first level and aggregate `sum`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
print (df)
   x      y    
   1  2   8  92
0  1  5  19  10
1  2  4   2   9
2  3  3   1   2
3  4  2   3   4

df = df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).sum()
print (df)
   x   y
0  6  29
1  6  11
2  6   3
3  6   7
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option, you can extract the prefix from the column names and use it as a group variable:

```
df.groupby(by = df.columns.str.split('.').str[0], axis = 1).sum()

#   x   y
#0  6   29
#1  6   11
#2  6   3
#3  6   7
```